# Como criar uma animação 2d como se fosse um vídeo, vinheta ou cutscene

Tags: javascript, animação, vídeo, 2d

Olá, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de criar uma animação complexa em HTML5 / Javascript. Por animação complexa quero dizer animação não cíclica como normalmente é mostrado em tutoriais.

Preciso criar uma animação como se fosse uma cutscene com imagens, transformações sobre essas imagens como se fosse uma vinheta ou um vídeo 2d.

Estou tendo dificuldade em determinar os tempos em que cada aparição (de imagem) ou transformação sobre as imagens ocorre. Criar esse codificação da timeline não está dando muito certo.

Existe algum framework ou software para esse tipo de animação?

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Márcio, acredito que você tenha os conhecimentos necessários para fazer o que você está falando correto? Só de ser uma animação complexa já tiramos dai que você deve possuir uma base em js e afins ou *(está em um bom periodo criativo rs)*.

De só uma olhada neste framework [three.js](https://threejs.org/)

Repare que na página inicial tem diversos exemplos de quão brilhante é essa ferramenta. Existem coisas ali que abrem minha boca toda vez que vejo. rs.